# TableView Sliding in Code

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I make the tableview to stop sliding initially? But it should slide when keyboard is visible.

I have written code for keyboarddidshow and hide methods, but it doesn't work if I deselect enable sliding option in IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

in ViewDidLoad and

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

in textFieldDidBeginEditing

Answer (score 0):

you can set the propery of setcontentOffset to the table

Comment: Can u please explain it in detail coz i dont know how to do it.